# Apache mod_rewrite URL

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

Hi I need some help with mod_rewrite.

I would like to change this kind of URL

```
127.0.0.1/app/controller/<anyName1>/<anyName2>.php?firstParam=1&secondParam=text&...&nParam=nSomething
```

to `127.0.0.1/anyName1/anyName2/1/text/.../nSomething`

Could you give me any example how to do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can save yourself *a lot* of stress by not trying to modify anything beyond `/<anyName1>/<anyName2>/` with `mod_rewrite`. Dynamically mapping path components to query variables requires some very funky recursive voodoo magic.

Instead grab only `/<anyName1>/<anyName2>/`, append the rest of the path to the redirect, and then use PHP to parse the path:

**.htaccess**

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/app/controller/[^/]+/[^/]+\.php
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/([^/]+)/?(.*)$ /app/controller/$1/$2.php/$3 [L]
```

**PHP**

```
$components = array_filter(explode('/', $_SERVER['PATH_INFO']), 'strlen');

echo '<pre>';
print_r($components);
echo '</pre>';
```

Output:

```
Array
(
    [1] => 1
    [2] => text
    [3] => ...
    [4] => nSomething
)
```